# dependencies between 2 fields in a schema type in graphql

Tags: graphql

I am looking for a way to describe chema level dependency between fields of an object type
for example:

```
    type foo{    
       obj1: MyOBJ1    
       obj2: MyOBJ2 
    }
```

in the backend data only obj1 or obj2 can be pupolated while the other must be null. they can never be populated together or be null together.
what is my best approach here?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types are always specific to an individual field. A field is nullable by default, or it can be non-null. That is the extent GraphQL will validate your output with regards to nullability. Any validation beyond that would have to take place at the resolver level.

That said, you could achieve a similar effect using an union or an interface.

```
type Query {
  foo: Foo
}
type Foo1 {    
  obj1: MyObj1!
}
type Foo2 {
  obj2: MyObj2! 
}
union Foo = Foo1 | Foo2
```

Making each field non-null ensures that *for the given type*, the field cannot be null. At runtime, a field with the type `Foo` will always resolve to one of the two concrete types (`Foo1` or `Foo2`). Therefore, if we query the `foo` field, we'll get either

```
{
  "foo": {
    "obj1": {...}
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "foo": {
    "obj2": {...}
  }
}
```

Note that in this case, `obj1` or `obj2` will **not** be null in the response -- rather it will be absent from the response altogether.

Comment: @user1061835 Please see my edit for additional details